# regression line issue in vegalite charts

Tags: vega-lite, vega-embed, vegas-viz

I want to create regression line in chart between the two points of data provided by the user.

I tried using EXTENT present in REGRESSION in VEGALITE but its not working. [editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXAdgAyoDQjgUwgczhiQCYBWTEKAQxmqVAFcAnAGyStuoHoBbAewBuEHAGcAdACtR-AHYgAvllbUAnjmZIA2qF7VmAawYgYqgA44OZ-hFnEsAMwitWOKEhjNGOJSByyAY34oW3xjAA9jJxxWd0QQACV+GBh-AAIAFX49GH4xNITaUJAsUwsOAEdGajsIOhgIQUtfVSiRWI4ASQBZABEAIQKi2TDS80t4qpqG+sbmhSVdfSNEUDKJkFZbSywg1n5NeKdmHAAjZggAo19PGtEHA95tUBP8E9FRCDkuvsHChpGJRA33iSRS6SyOTyoiGANGfnCqTs2hImAoAF0FOisP4giFAasQJFCdEOqDkkjMtlaNDYcUxuVJtVarMmoosK0Se04iAegM6YCGRspiyimyFlh3vxWGzCaIAtRXBEOLYoDgLLI1ciFliFEA) .
Please help me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think this may be related to this bug? https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/3838